# Running into a tuple index error while creating a deepVAR model

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, mxnet-gluon

The following is the code I wrote so far for my gluonts deepvar model. I'm trying to use multiple time series to make a prediction and gluonts seemed to be a good option for that. The following below are screenshots of what I've done so far and the error I'm receiving.
[Dataset loader code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IppVt.png)

[deepVAR model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Pw5.png)

[error I'm receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JDww.png)

Comment: You should paste the code instead of screenshots

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)